# How to debug a web project in local with multiple web.config

Tags: xml, web, app-config

In a web project, I used the "Add config Transforms" on the "web.config" file to create a different web.config in function of the build configuration. When I publish the website on a local folder, I can check the web.config built with XML transformations is good.  But when I run the application in local machine, the Visual Studio Developper Server (Cassini) take the web.config source, without doing XML transformations.

Do you know how to run the application in local with the web.config built in function of the build configuration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is part of the deployment process and not part of the build process. Therefore, it is expected behavior.

One thing you can do is to deploy your code to a folder and then copy over the transformed web.config file to the folder you are debugging from. This might be cumbersome especially if your web.config files are changing a lot.